# cannot run git pull after git checkout

Tags: git

I am new to git and I am trying to see the merge conflicts that i will have if i merge changes from  Branch `A` to Branch `B`.
so these are the steps i followed

1. cloned the repo using `git clone`
2. cd to the cloned repo and `git checkout A`
3. `git pull B`

on the 3rd step i am getting this error

```
git pull B
fatal: 'B' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But i can access this branch `B` via the bitbucket URL and it is a branch in the same repo.
Can someone guide me with the right process here.
My goal is to see the merge conflicts and resolve them.

Comment: You want to pull what is in branch `origin/B`? Then it should be `git pull origin B`.

Comment: actually its ```feature/B``` and ```git pull feature/B``` did not work either

Comment: Look at the command I provided _carefully_ (tip: `origin` is a remote, `B` is a branch).